# Adblock plus not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, adblock

Quite simply Ad block plus isn't working. It used to work, now it doesn't. I tried disabling and re enabling the extension to no effect. In Google searches I see ads. What should I try?

Also a number of times I had liked to test a new Adblock plus instillation, is there a site designed to test if Adblock plus is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has recently changed their way of placing ads on their searches, therefore making any previous methods of blocking on Google ads to not function. Use Adblock Plus' secondary add-on to allow the functionality of manually removing ads using your current installation of Adblock Plus: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any websites designed to test if Adblock plus is working properly?

Comment: Try going to a website like addictinggames.com and see what happens when you disable and re-enable adblock. If ads appear and then disappear, then your installation of adblock is working correctly ;)

Comment: Yea I see what you mean, though it's not that easy. For example it is not apparant which images should be blocked, for example one may wrongfully concluded that the "what's new in monkey quest" is an ad and therefore Adblock plus isn't working. Also on mobile devices (e.g. Android) such a site could be hard to load an view.